# SubSonic configuration error

Tags: sql-server-2005, orm, configuration, subsonic

**I am receiving error:**

Building configuration from `Web.config`
Can't set the configuration for the providers. There is an error with your config setup (did you remember to configure SubSonic in your config file?). 'An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for SubSonicService: Could not load type 'SubSonic.SubSonicSection ' from assembly 'SubSonic'. (Web.config line 13)'
There's a problem with the providers - none were loaded and no exceptions where thrown.
Setting ConfigPath: 'Web.config'

but here are my configuration sections and I am using **Visual Studio 2010**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="SubSonicService" type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection ,SubSonic" requirePermission="true" restartOnExternalChanges="true" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="TasksConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="*"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <SubSonicService defaultProvider="SqlDataProvider" spClassName="SPs" fixPluralClassNames="true">
    <providers>
      <add name="SqlDataProvider" type="SubSonic.SqlDataProvider, SubSonic" connectionStringName="TasksConnnection"/>
    </providers>
  </SubSonicService>
    <compilation>
      <buildProviders>
        <add type="SubSonic.BuildProvider,SubSonic" extension="*.abp"/>
      </buildProviders>
</compilation>
</configuration>
```

and i have a file `Builder.abp` with just `*` inside it. Also as said in documentation and other sites it automatically does not generate classes when i build web application project i have to manually invoke subsonic commander (sonic.exe) executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used the builder, but the basic idea is there are two different approaches.  The builder which would create the Subsonic service dynamically on *execution*, and commander which would actually generate code files for *compilation*.

- If you are generating the physical classes, you don't need the buildProvider section - maybe that's confusing it?
- In your code are you using the compiled classes to do the queries?
- Try a more standard connection string?